# Android file security

Tags: android, security, file

Is it possible to provide application specific security to the files?. I want the file could only be accessed by the desired application and not by the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have files stored on the sd-card in mind, since files stored in the internal file system is protected by default.

The only way you can protect your data from other applications is to use some sort of encryption.

Android gives each application its own user id and then the standard Linux file system access rights take care of protecting data stored on the internal file system. There is nothing you need to do to take advantage of this feature, as it is central to the whole security model in Android.

But for external storage, like the sd-card, Android is using the FAT file system to make the cards compatible with Windows. It's a good thought, but since the FAT file system lack any access rights features, everything stored on the sd-card is available to all apps. (An app that needs access to the sd-card will need to ask for permission to do so.)

(This is a huge integrity problem with Android. Sensitive information should not be stored on the sd-card, yet all photos taken are stored there. An app with access to the sd-card and the internet could easily upload all your photos to a server somewhere without you knowing it.)

Answer (score 0):

you can play with the permission by declaring in your AndroidManifest.xml file. As stated in Android developer permission guide:.

For example, an application that wants to control who can start one of its activities could declare a permission for this operation as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.app.myapp" >
    <permission android:name="com.me.app.myapp.permission.DEADLY_ACTIVITY"
        android:label="@string/permlab_deadlyActivity"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_deadlyActivity"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.COST_MONEY"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Can you check the [webpage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html) and if you are not clear we can discuss here, i have to go over before giving the exact answer.

Edit: Also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571783/file-permissions-in-android) in so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  A simple solution is to generate a random cryptographic key using `/dev/urandom` when the app is installed, store the key in local storage (not on the SD card), and then encrypt the files you store on the SD card using this key.  This will prevent other apps from reading the files.

Of course, one consequence of this approach is that the user will not be able to remove the SD card, put it into their PC, and copy those files onto their PC.