# Including compiled executables and libraries with gradle (android)

Tags: android, android-ndk, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've added the following to my build.gradle to include pre-compiled binaries and shared objects in my jni folder.

```
sourceSets {
  main {
     jniLibs.srcDir file('jni/')
  }
}
```

But when I build and inspect the APK, the .so files are included, but the binaries are not. Is it possible for gradle to bundle the compiles binaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the goal is to store .so files that are automatically extracted upon installation.

Anything custom should go in your assets folder.

Comment: So then... I should put the native binaries in the assets folder, and then at runtime copy them, make them executable and run them?

Comment: That would be the right approach but I'm not sure if it'll work. You'll also need to manually figure out the ABI of the device and use the right binary.

Comment: Yeah, it seems overkill. I think it would be better to just include the binaries inside the libs folder in the apk using a gradle task, just like how the previous build systems do (unless I'm missing something fundamental?)

Comment: Neither Ant nor ADT will package anything but .so

Comment: That can't be true, as I have project that includes a FFMPEG binary (libs/armeabi/ffmpeg) which gets included in the final apk (lib/armeabi/ffmpeg).

Comment: Interesting. What build system are you using?

Comment: This was using intellij about a year ago. I can't seem to find any documentation to support bundling of native binaries in this way so I figure it was a mistake of the build system and I should seek an alternate method (this answer seems promising http://stackoverflow.com/a/5642593/315998)

Comment: It seems in Android 10, you can't copy the executables out any more. You have to run them from the right location.