# android Use Linux tools stored at assets folder

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, iperf

I want to use tools from Linux which not available in Android by default such as iw and iperf. I saw Android applications that use this tools (like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magicandroidapps.iperf&hl=en)). There are two ways to do it.

**First:** get root rights on device and put file of the tool to the `system/bin/` folder.

**Second:** put file of  the tool to `assets` folder of Android project and somehow use it.

Applications from Play Market use second way. But I don't know, how it cuold be done. Is there any description of implementation of second way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/

This the best example of what you want to do.

For putting executable in assest see 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642593/775964

Comment: Jeegar Patel, thank you for your reply. I know how to open and to use usual file, but I don't know how can I use these tools which represented like files without any extension and was built using C++ source code specially for Android

Comment: those files are just  executable files compiled for ARM architecture for android.  so you can use it just like another executable.

Comment: I didn't see second link. I'll try to use your advice and than accept you answer. It looks like very useful. Thank you.

Comment: That link is 1st answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583487/hosting-an-executable-within-android-application/5642593#5642593