# Hosting an executable within a Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a basic flutter project running on android where when the application starts, I write an executable bundled in my assets.

```
  static String appInternalPath = '/data/data/com.maksimdan.face_merger';

  void writeExecutable() async {
    var executablePath = join(appInternalPath, 'main');

    if (await File(executablePath).exists()) {
      File(executablePath).delete();
      print('deleted old executable');
    } else {
      print('not executable exists');
    }

    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('lib/py/dist/main');
    List<int> bytes =
        data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    await File(executablePath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    print('wrote new executable');
  }
```

Sometime later in my code I try to run it.

```
  void invokeExecutable() async {
    String executablePath = join(appInternalPath, 'main');
    Process.run('chmod', ['u+x', executablePath]).then((ProcessResult results) {
      Process.run(executablePath, []).then((ProcessResult results) {
        print(results.stdout);
      });
    });
  }
```

But obtain a permission denied error.

```
E/flutter (31825): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: ProcessException: Permission denied
E/flutter (31825):   Command: /data/data/com.maksimdan.flutter_general/main 
E/flutter (31825): #0      _ProcessImpl._start (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:390:33)
E/flutter (31825): #1      Process.start (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:36:20)
E/flutter (31825): #2      _runNonInteractiveProcess (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:565:18)
E/flutter (31825): #3      Process.run (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:47:12)
E/flutter (31825): #4      _MyHomePageState.invokeExecutable.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_general/main.dart:51:15)
E/flutter (31825): #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (31825): #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (31825): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I've also tried:

```
      Process.run('/system/bin/chmod', ['744', path]).then((ProcessResult results) {
        print('shell1 complete');
        Process.run(path, []).then((ProcessResult results) {
          print('shell2 complete');
          print(results.stdout);
        });
      });
```

My executable:

```cpp
// 'Hello World!' program 
 
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

```
>> g++ main.cc -o main
```

Is there a way to run your own executables in flutter with the proper permissions? On native android, there is an option to `file.setExecutable(true);` using this strategy. ([Hosting an executable within Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583487/hosting-an-executable-within-android-application))

Or will I have to experiment with method channels?

---

pubspec.yml

```
name: face_merger
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  sqflite: ^1.3.0+2
  process_run: ^0.10.10+1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - lib/py/dist/main
```

I also verified that the file was written to the internal memory of on the device that I expected it to be written to using android studio's device explore.

[image: screenshot of executable within the android simulator]

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: @Eiko android platform

Comment: interestingly running `chmod` on the same path executable gives a `Unhandled Exception: ProcessException: No such file or directory`, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: can you share the pubspec.yaml packages that you using.

Comment: Can it be related to place of  your project installation? Maybe the path you want to write needs some administator permission from your os?

Comment: @SanjeevSangral I've added the pubspec. I also included a screenshot that shows the executable existing (with what appears only read and write permissions)

Comment: @onesiumus did you ever get the answer to this question?

Comment: @GroovinChip Unfortunately not using this strategy. Eventually I resolved interfacing it through dart ffi (read more here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the writable permission you need to have readable permission in your app.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx.yyy">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

...

Comment: I tried this as well for completness. The executable is being written in the phones internal memory, not external.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the .db file extension at the end of the database name (Assuming DB_DIR is for a database). var path = join(DB_DIR, 'main.db');

Then I think you may want to use [path_provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) and use

```
Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

for the directory where you are accessing the database.

Comment: I initially used db_dir as placeholder name; sorry for the confusion; I've edited the question. But I am not interested in copying over a database. Its is an executable that can be run over the terminal. I've shown that copying over the executable is not the issue, but its attempt of executing it within the application that fails.