# android - system app jni library load path

Tags: android, android-ndk

If android installed at below path:

```
/system/product/priv-app/mynative/app-debug.apk
```

And this apk contains a jni library:

```
app-debug/lib/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so
```

Where is the path android to load the library libnative-lib.so? I search device and never find that so file.

Comment: Given that `libnative-lib.so` is packaged inside the apk, you should expand on who and when is looking for that file. Possibly related: [How to correctly find native lib path in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63134761/295004)

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be: "it never was on the filesystem to begin with".

Modern Android build infrastructure sets [extractNativeLibraries=false](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size#extract-false) by default. This keeps the .so in the APK instead of having a copy linger on your device.

EDIT: I did some source digging, the Android runtime linker [can open libraries directly from zip files](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:bionic/linker/linker.cpp;l=882;drc=master) if the filename contains `!/`. I think this would just show up as another mapping of the APK in /proc/pid/maps, but I did not investigate beyond that (eg how relocation is done in this case or what namespaces have to do with it).

Comment: @Bctje Thanks, how System.loadLibrary() find it then? if I cat /proc/pid/maps file, I do not see jni libraries either!

Comment: @lucky1928 See edit. I think that explains what you are seeing.